# Getting started with p2p type networking/programming

Tags: c++, networking, p2p

I am learning C++ (as in, I am installing Visual Studio now, and I'm holding Horton's book in my hand), and my reason for doing so is that I want to write a p2p type client/server program that will allow users to stream video from a device without needing port forwarding (and save loads of time on tech support calls).

I want the user to register the device with the home server through the device menu (engineers will take care of that) and then on a PC, log into a client and add the device to a proverbial "friends list" of devices using the password they used on the machine. Then, at any time, they could open the device and and control it over the web without the need for port forwarding.

Sort of the way Skype works, I guess. The users can stream audio/video to each other without knowing each other's IP address or forwarding any ports.

Can someone please give me an overview of how that will work, and the networking considerations I will need to account for when programming the main server and client? I don't even know where to start... I don't need help with the programming, just how the communication infrastructure will look. How does a client discover a device on a p2p network and then communicate with it, without knowing the IP address before hand, or without having any ports for information or commands entering the remote network to be routed to the device?

I've been reading about p2p networking, and I understand the basic idea of p2p architecture, but not the actual theory and method of communicating via p2p.

Comment: Just to clarify, this isn't my first programming language, but it is my first compiled language. I've been doing a lot of PHP and VB programming. So I'm not starting from scrap.

Answer (score 0):

> How does a client discover a device on a p2p network and then communicate with it, without knowing the IP address before hand, or without having any ports for information or commands entering the remote network to be routed to the device?

You can't create a p2p IP connection across the internet without either knowing the IP address beforehand or having some known server to connect to to ask.  I.e. one side must proactively register it's own server address and port number with some manner of server that the other side queries.

Comment: Ok, yeah I just read the part about bootstrapping on pure p2p networks. Maybe it would be better to do a centralized server that handles the queries and connects the clients? If that's the case, how do the client and device communicate without port forwarding?

Comment: Dexter: the central server just needs to tell one of the clients the other's IP and listening server port number, then that client can connect directly to the other client.

Answer (score 0):

If your devices are limited to work within single network, you can use [zero configuration networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking) to avoid communication through server. [Multicast DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) might be a good choice to discover all devices or services within the network.

If you want the devices to work over the internet you will make your life harder. Let's assume your network is going to be small and hence you want every device to know about each other, so you can stream video from each to each. You can think about a centralised component which keeps track of all devices and is willing to share this information with others. It might be a simple http server, which you can query for addresses of all other devices. Every query would automatically register a querying device and all other devices can discover it once they requery the server.

This is basically how BitTorrent tracker works. With a limitation though – only peers allowing for incoming connections are being kept in the list. It makes sense, as the konwledge about a peer behind a NAT is pretty useless, as you cannot reach it anyway. You can only hope it will query the tracker and discover you.

Now, if two peers are behind the NAT, they're not able to reach each other. At least in cases where the P2P protocol is not too sophisticated. BitTorrent wouldn't allow for this, while Skype would. It could be solved by streaming data through one of the devices with public IP or through some dedicated server (the latter is probably worse as less scalable).

I'll stop now... There're are a lot of problems with designing such protocol over the Internet and it depends on what *exactly* you need. So, do you need it to work over the Internet or just within local network? I'm happy to discuss it more deeply if you provide more details.